# MATLAB R2014a Installation pointed to wrong licence file. How can I again get to select the licence path?

Tags: matlab, installation

MATLAB R2014a Installation pointed to wrong licence file. How can I again get to select the licence path ?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96751-how-do-i-update-my-matlab-license-file-for-an-individual-or-designated-computer-license